# Confluent Schema Registry - 405 error after creating topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am running a local version of Confluent (4.0) on MacOS and after starting it up and creating a topic `newtopic` and going to `http://localhost:18081/subjects/newtopic` - getting following error:
`{"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}`

Going to `http://localhost:18081/` works fine.

What should I check and how to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting a `POST` to that [REST endpoint](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html#post--subjects-(string- subject)).

Check out the [quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/intro.html#quickstart) for examples of using the Schema Registry.